# Changing touch handling from parent to child view

Tags: android

I am intending to transfer a touch event from a parent view to its child. I tried some constructions but so far I have not succeeded to assign touch handling to another view, but only delegating touch handling from parent to child views, which is not quite the same.

This is what I like to achieve:

[image: The green dot is a Touch Down Event on the parent, then I am dragging towards another view, which is than picked up on the blue spot (fireing Touch Down on the child viee) and from this point the parent view is not involved anymore.]

The green dot is a Touch Down Event on the parent, then I am dragging towards another view, which is than picked up on the blue spot (firing Touch-Down on the child view) and from this point the parent view is not involved anymore, like I would have touched the child in the first place.

I could delegate the touch event by extending the parents onTouchEvent method, and then calling  child.dispatchTouchEvent(), when entering the childs view-bounds, but I would like to avoid the parents involvement.

Answer (score 0):

From the [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) documentation, the return of an OnTouch() is:

> Returns
>
> ```
> True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.
> ```

Basically, if you want the parent to react to the onTouchListener, return false. If you want it to not react, return true.

Comment: That is true, but when I am returning false (while ACTION-MOVE is dispached), the touch Event is not propagated to any child view.